# Laravel Passport: revoke existing access tokens and refresh token before granting a new one

Tags: laravel-passport

I have a mobile app that utilizes the Laravel Passport. I want to enforce one authenticated device only. If user A signs in with device A, then user A signs in with device B.

DeviceB is authenticated, and device A is no longer authenticated

If user A signs in with device A again, device A now is authenticated and device B is not.

I am not sure where to implement this and how to do this? Ideally, before generating a new access token/refresh token to a new device, all existing tokens/refresh tokens need to be revoked or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

as i found you want to revoke last token when new login request send to server, so when you generate a new token last token deprecate automatically for example if you use client_credential grant type, you obtain a client_id and client_secret for your user and before any request to server user should pass this client info and get token, so last token revoke automatically this request can be from the same device or different device that not important, just send client info to server and get new access token